# @Autowired for @ModelAttribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired, modelattribute

I'm very new to Spring and I'm encountering the following problem.

I've got the following Controller, in which the @Autowired works perfectly (tried debugging and it works fine).

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration")
@SessionAttributes("rf")
public class RegistrationController
{
    @Autowired
    UserJpaDao userDao;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Transactional
    public String setupForm(Model model) throws Exception
    {
        model.addAttribute("rf", new RegistrationForm());
        return "registration";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("rf") RegistrationForm rf, Model model) throws Exception
    {
        // ...

        User user = rf.getUser();
        userDao.save(user);

        // ...

        return "registration";
    }
}
```

But when I submit my form, the @Autowired field in my RegistrationForm remains null.

RegistrationForm.java:

```
@Component
public class RegistrationForm
{
    @Autowired
    CountryJpaDao countryDao;

    // ... fields...

    public RegistrationForm()
    {

    }

    @Transactional
    public User getUser() throws InvalidUserDataException
    {
        //...

        Country c = countryDao.findByCode("GB"); // Throws java.lang.NullPointerException

        // ...
    }

    // ... getters/setters...
}
```

Here is the form's HTML/JSTL:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="rf">
    ...
</form:form>
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

(inspired by [this post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?105380-Autowired-for-ModelAttribute) on SpringSource forums)

Comment: Please paste your spring config applicationContext.xml or another. Check   <context:component-scan base-package="test.example"/>
        <context:annotation-config/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up your concepts here.  You use the likes of `@Component` and `@Autowired` for Spring-managed beans, and `@ModelAttribute` for transient, throwaway objects that are used to bind form data.  The two should not be mixed.  Your `@Component` and `@Autowired` annotations on `RegistrationForm` will be ignored by Spring, because they're not appropriate in that context.

Classes like `RegistrationForm` should represent the form data, and nothing else. Typically,  the controller would ask `RegistrationForm` for the user ID, and would then look at the actual `User` object from the DAO itself. If you want `RegistrationForm` to look up the `User` itself, then your controller needs to manually supply the DAO to `RegistrationForm` when it asks for the `User` object.

As far as that post on the Spring forum is concerned, you'll notice that it never received an answer.  It's not a good source to take inspiration from.

Note that I'm not saying that desiring to autowire beans into a form back object is a bad idea, I'm just saying that Spring doesn't do that.

Comment: Thank you @skaffman -- this is what I thought. Unfortunately I can't "translate" directly the registration form fields to the User class. For example the registration form has three fields for the date of birth (day, month and year) while the User class uses a Datetime. Is there any Spring solution to this? I created the RegistrationForm class containing all the form fields as String and I was hoping to return a User instance with a getUser() method (reading the RegistrationForm instance fields), but I need the Autowired Country DAO for it to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It would work if you use the @Configurable annotation on your model, and this aspectJ configuration on your gradle file:

```
compileJava << {
    ant.taskdef(
        resource: 'org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties',
        classpath: configurations.compile.asPath)

    ant.iajc(
        inpath: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.absolutePath,
          classpath: configurations.compile.asPath,
          aspectPath: configurations.aspects.asPath,
          destDir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.absolutePath
    )
}
```

In this way aspectJ will generate code that does the auto wiring.

```
@Configurable
public class RegistrationForm
{
   ...
}
```