# Spring 3 MVC: @ModelAttribute method + @Autowired not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications

I am new to Spring and trying to learn @Autowired magic in SPring MVC. I was trying out a demo application using the @ModelAttribute method and @Autowired. Every time I am getting `null` which means @Autowired is not happening properly. Below is what I tried:

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class ModelAttributeAutoWiredController {

@Autowired
private Employee empl;

public void setEmpl(Employee empl) {
    this.empl = empl;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/home")
public ModelAndView returnhome(){

    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("home");
    System.out.println("Employee First Name: " + empl.getFirstName()); // NULL
    return modelView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/index")
public ModelAndView returnindex(){

    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("index");
    System.out.println("Employee Last Name: " + empl.getLastName()); // NULL
    return modelView;
}

@ModelAttribute("empl")
public Employee populateEmployee(){
    Employee empl = new Employee();
    empl.setFirstName("XXX");
    empl.setLastName("YYY");
    return empl;
}
```

}

**Employee**

```
@Component
public class Employee {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
}
```

**context xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.pack" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Can someone please help me out in the above code and make me understand why @Autowired is not working?

Comment: share the bean configuration

Comment: Apart from this, I dont have anything in my context file, only the namespaces in the `<beans>....</beans>`. I know I need to add something in the context but not what changes shall I do so that whatever returned by the `@ModelAttribute` is injected into the @Autowired. Please help

Comment: Note that you don't need a setter method for an autowired field, even a private one.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what's happening, not just "getting null". Spring will abort loading if it can't autowire a field, so I'm inclined to believe your problem is elsewhere, and you seem to be unclear on the purpose of `ModelAttribute`; it injects into the model, not into fields.

Comment: Additionally, your employee class definitely should not be a `Component`, which is for service or configuration objects, not data objects.

Comment: @chrylis In the above code, when I rpint the `Sysout` statements in the controller methods, then the Employee First and LAst name are getting pringted as `null` which means the values are not getting set from the `populateEmployee` mtethod.

Comment: I have a full writeup but can't get it to post. Short version: You are completely misunderstanding both `@Component` and `@ModelAttribute`.

Comment: May be :( Can you please explain them once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing several Spring concepts here.

First, `@Component` is used for *program* components, generally objects that provide some service that other pieces of the program need. It is *not* intended for data objects such as your `Employee` class, and data objects that are runtime data (and not configuration objects) shouldn't be autowired, they should be passed in to the specific method calls that operate on them.

`@ModelAttribute` tells Spring that it should add whatever is being annotated to the MVC `Model` object so that it's available to the controller and view. This has nothing to do at all with `@Autowired`.

Here's what's happening in your code:

- Your `Employee` class is annotated `@Component`, so Spring creates a singleton bean and registers it in the context. This bean never has its fields set, so they're `null`, but the bean itself exists, so it's wired into your controller's `empl` field. This is why you don't get a `NullPointerException`, which you would if the autowiring really weren't working.
- Your `@ModelAttribute` is evaluated by Spring and added to the `Model` for each request. However, you never pass this model to any of your controllers, so they never see it.
- Your controller methods create new, empty `ModelAndView` objects with nothing in them.
- They then read the completely different, empty `Employee` object that was injected into `empl` and print out the `null` value on the fields (but don't throw `NullPointerException`s because the autowiring succeeded).

Answer (score 1):

Please check this: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-xml-example/

You'll need the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` and also the `<context:component-scan base-package="com.your.package" />` in your context.xml file.

Looks like this isn't possible and if you think about it, it doesn't make much sense to have a `@ModelAttribute` as an instance variable. Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9253867/2231632) to get a better understanding.

Comment: I added them but still not working... In the sysout statements above, I am getting the employee First and LAst names as null.

Comment: we need your entire context xml file. And aren't you declare your methods with @ModelAttribute or your methods should have a parameter annotated with @ModelAttribute? Like shown below:
`@RequestMapping(value="/index") 
@ModelAttribute
public ModelAndView returnindex()` or `public ModelAndView myMethod(@ModelAttribute empl){..}` ? How else Spring will know when to invoke your ModelAttribute code?

Comment: posted the entire `context.xml` file. I have this in index.jsp file: `<a href="home">Go To Home</a>` hence the method is invoked accordingly.

Comment: Have you actually read through the documentation? Please go through this and let us know if you understood it all: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib I believe that covers everything you need to know to get this to work.

Comment: I read but being a newbie, did not understood much hence trying to break it up with some small working demos like this one. Can you please help me in this?

Comment: Can you come on chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52052/discussion-between-user182944-and-prabugp)

Answer (score 1):

@Autowired is not intended for the domain objects like Employee.
In your case Spring creates an Employee object using the default constructor, so its lastname is null. Spring creates the Employee object because of @Component annotation on the Employee class, it has nothing to do with the @ModelAttribute.
The method annotated with @ModelAttributes instructs Spring to create another Employee object and inject it to the Model object that you don't have to create by yourself.
Just return "index" String from your "returnhome" method.
For debugging, you may add @ModelAttribute Employee e as an argument to your "returnhome" method.